# Backbone.js + Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: sql, web-applications, backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I have been trying to follow the guide at http://coenraets.org/directory/

I have the contents of the "Web" folder copied onto the root of my website and the page appears just fine, I also installed his sql script into my database. The search bar isn't working (probably since my SQL database requires a username and password?). How do I fix this?

Comment: my server is located at http://98.214.131.200

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that you have set up slim to run the php application that receives the javascript calls from backbone.js?

Reference - https://github.com/ccoenraets/backbone-directory/blob/master/api/index.php

The API directory contains a file named `index.php`.  For the php slim framework (http://www.slimframework.com/) in this application, it should contain your database IP, username and password.

Lines 148 onwards in the `index.php` file.

```
function getConnection() {
    $dbhost="127.0.0.1";
    $dbuser="root";
    $dbpass="";
    $dbname="directory";
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);  
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return $dbh;
}
```

Your server location -  98.214.131.200 - does not matter if you have set this php application on that server itself.  `127.0.0.1` refers to the server localhost itself.

What you need to configure is the `$dbuser` and `$dbpass` (your `$dbname` is obviously correct since you mentioned that that's the MySQL db you created by running the provided sql script)  which corresponds to the MySQL database you have set up for this demo app.

If you are using `apache` to run slim, make sure `mod_rewrite` is enabled and configure your apache virtualhost to be something like:-

```
<Directory "C:\Path\To\Your\slimphp">
    Allow From All
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName "slim.php"
    DocumentRoot "C:\Path\To\Your\slimphp"
</VirtualHost>
```

Ah, if using IIS as @vicvicvic has pointed out, use ModRewrite - http://www.micronovae.com/ModRewrite/ModRewrite.html

Comment: function getConnection() {
 $dbhost="127.0.0.1";
    $dbuser="root";
    $dbpass="mypassword";
    $dbname="directory";
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);  
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return $dbh;
}

I have the function set like this but it's still not working, any other ideas as to what the issue could be?

Comment: So just to clarify, your php slim application is served by `apache` (mod_php) or `fastcgi` or some kind of webserver,  yes?

Comment: @vicvicvic has correctly pointed out that your php application's url isn't configured properly.

Comment: How do I properly configure it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the backend in the `api` folder so that it actually communicates with your SQL database. Do this in the `getConnection` function in `api/index.php`:

```
function getConnection() {
    $dbhost="127.0.0.1";
    $dbuser="root";
    $dbpass="";
    $dbname="directory";
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);  
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return $dbh;
}
```

Comment: After putting in my username and password this still didn't work. I do have php installed ( http://98.214.131.200/test.php ) so I am baffled as to what the issue could be. Any ideas?

Comment: You should have the api running at http://98.214.131.200/api/employees for this to work (I get a 404 when accessing it); compare with http://coenraets.org/directory/api/employees

Comment: Well, first of all you need to put the `api` folder in the directory from where you're serving your files. It seems you've put just the `web` folder at the root of your server. You need to put `web` and `api` there (so you'll acess the web interface through /web). Also, you're running IIS -- but the sample is made to run on Apache (with the .htaccess file). You need to figure out how you can redirect all requests under the api folder to the index.php file on IIS...